# Given a set, how will you generate it permutations / subsets (Skiena method)?

Tags: algorithm, backtracking

I am trying to understand the Skeina methodology of solving backtracking problems.

How would you solve following variations of permutations using Skiena method:

- Generate all combinations possible:

  - Input: ["a", "b", "c"]
  - Output: ["a", "b", "c", "ab", "ac", "ba" .... "abc"]

P.S: I am getting lost in the text and not able to develop the understanding from code snippets given in the book. but would be able to easily understand if you can share a complete program. I sincerely appreciate your effort here.

Comment: I just copy pasted the C code of the book (section 7) and it works. I don't know what you're missing... Read the whole section carefully.

Comment: What is the Skeina methodology?  What do you mean by backtracking problems?  At a guess, you've really got a question about how to think about recursion, but it would take some back and forth before your actual points of confusion became clear.